# JavaFX ListView shape color

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to set different colors to shape according by user status on ListView. But when I scroll the ListView some another cells change its shapes too as an example:

I need my shapes like this (each rectangle is inside a cell) :

[image: Image 1]

But after some scrolls, they stay like this:

[image]

This is part of my code:

```
userListView.setCellFactory(userCell -> new UserCellController());
```

Class UserCellController:

```
public class UserCellController extends ListCell<UserPopulate> {

    @FXML
    private Rectangle statusShape;

    private FXMLLoader mLLoader;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(UserPopulate user, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(user, empty);

        if(empty || user == null) {

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

        } else {

            if (mLLoader == null) {
                mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/userCell.fxml"));
                mLLoader.setController(this);

                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            if ( user.getUserStatus().toString().equals("3") ) {
                statusShape.setFill(Color.RED);
            }

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(cellPane);

        }

    }

}
```

I need that only the second cell (with user status == 3) with RED shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `else` to go with your `if`:

```
// surely you shouldn't actually be testing for string equality here?
if ( user.getUserStatus().toString().equals("3") ) {
    statusShape.setFill(Color.RED);
} else {
    // or whatever the default color is...
    statusShape.setFill(Color.BLUE);
}
```

The issue is that if a cell that held a user with status `3`, and is then reused (e.g. during the user scrolling) to hold a user with a different status, then the color will not be reset unless you explicitly code for it.

The basic rule is that the code in `updateItem()` needs to cover all cases.

Comment: OMG! How did I not think of that? Thanks James!!